# Adicionando um EditText dinamicamente e modificar as propriedades layout_width, layout_height e

Tags: android, android-layout

Estou tentando adicionar dois *EditText* dinamicamente, até ai tudo bem.
Agora como que eu faço para mexer na propriedade de peso na tela, só consigo utilizar `wrap_content` ou `match_parent`.

Answer (score 1):

Deverá criar um [LinearLayout.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html), definir o valor de peso no atributo [weight](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#weight) e depois atribuí-lo ao *EditText*:

```
//Cria um objecto LinearLayout.LayoutParams
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

//Atribui o valor desejado ao weight
params.weight = valorDesejado;

//Atribui os parâmetros ao EditText
editText.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Para outras propriedades veja a [documentação.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html)

Exemplo para as propriedades `layout_width` e `layout_height`

```
params.width = 10;
params.height = 5;
```

O mesmo pode ser conseguido no construtor:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(10, 5);
```